# Как сохранить изменения в css файле Yii2

Tags: css, yii2, phpstorm

Вношу изменения в css-файле, который подключен и благополучно работал, но почему-то сейчас изменения в нем не сохраняются, php-storm все сохранил, но на странице изменения не сохраняются вообще. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#cache-busting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте к адресу CSS-файла параметр. Например, время изменения файла

```
<link href="/file.css?20170701114700" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Также можно очищать кэш - ctrl+f5

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: работаете локально?

Comment: "работаете локально?" - удалённо. А какое отношение это имеет к вопросу?

Comment: Дело в том, что при заливке изменённого файла на удалённый сервер, если изменился владелец - как раз в таком случае всё останется по-старому.                       Также, возможно, что происходит дополнительное кэширование. Или же файл был залит не в ту папку.